# how to add specific logic to the method by custom annotation in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, inversion-of-control, spring-annotations

My question is this.

I would like to add custom annotation to spring boot and designate it as declared without declaring a specific logic.

Suppose you have the following code:

```
@MyCustomAnnotation
@Controller
public class ExController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I want the above code to perform the following logic.

```
@MyCustomAnnotation
@Controller
public class ExController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model){
        
        //Code added because it has an annotation
        
           model.addAttribute("key","value");  

        //Code added because it has an annotation
        
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I've been thinking about Reflection and other methods, but I can't think of the right way

Can someone grateful give a solution or keyword for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can add specific logic to the method by custom annotation in Spring boot by using the @Component annotation.
You can use `@Configuration` annotation to add your custom logic.

```
<code>@Configuration
public class MyCustomAnnotationConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyCustomAnnotationBean myCustomAnnotationBean() {
        return new MyCustomAnnotationBean();
    }
}
```

And then you can use `@Autowired` to inject your bean into your controller.
```
`@MyCustomAnnotation
@Controller
public class ExController {
@Autowired
private MyCustomAnnotationBean myCustomAnnotationBean;

@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model){
    myCustomAnnotationBean.doSomething();
    return "index";
}

}`

Comment: ANISH KUMAR

Thank you for your answer.

However, my question is not about how to create Bean, but how to add logic to the method without any additional processing if annotations are added.

Answer (score 0):

@RequestParam is a Spring annotation that is used to bind a parameter to the value of a method parameter.
If you want to add logic to your method, you can do so without any annotations.
`public ResponseEntity<String> myMethod(@RequestParam(required = false) String param) {
//additional logic
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}`

The above code will add additional logic to the method.

i hope this can be helpful i am new to this .